# Change message in Alert Popup - Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have this:

```
  doAlert() {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
           title: 'My Popup',
           message: this.updateStatus
      });
      alert.present()
  }

  this.updateStatus = 'Start';
  this.doAlert();

  setTimeout(() => {
      this.updateStatus = 'Finish';
      console.log('Done Timeout');
  }, 1000);
```

The alert shows only Start like picture below, even the console.log is trigger.

[image]

How can I trigger it to change the message to Finish?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to have a dynamic alert content. You can use Modal instead, and use a custom view to it.

Comment: have you tried `alert.setMessage('Finish');` ?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you can, I just tried it :). Its best if you use a loader(Alerts are normally for confirmation messages)

FYI: make sure your loader is global...

**Add this in your class**

```
loader: any;
```

**Add this in your Constructor:**

```
this.loader = loadingCtrl.create({
  content: "Logging in, Please wait..."
});
this.loader.dismissAll()
```

Then You can add this where you want your text to change

```
this.loader.data.content = "Still waiting ? LOL";
```

Comment: anyone stumbling upon this now, I recently had to change it to 

alert.data.subTitle = "string";

Answer (score 1):

Solution for **Ionic 5** (will also work with Ionic 4) if anybody is stumbling over this:

```
this.loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
    message: 'Please wait ...'
});
this.loader.present();
```

Then at some point in the future, update the message like this:

```
this.loader.message = 'Still waiting? ';
```